# pasar una variable numerica de javascript a css

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

nececito saber como pasar una variables de js a css.

```
<script>
        let infinito = 1;
        let aumento = 0;
        while (infinito == 1) {
            if (aumento <= 359) {
                aumento += 0.1;
                if (aumento == 359) {
                    aumento = 0;
                }; 
            };
           

        };

    </script>
```

con ese codigo hago que aumento suba hasta 359 y resetee y se preguntaran para que . la respuesta es simple es para un color de css es decir

```
.boton{

color:hsl(variable, 100, 100)
 

}
```

si alguien sabe que puedo hacer por favor seria de gran ayuda ya que tengo de trabajo final hacer una pagina web unica :)

Comment: una consulta , en donde viste que css puede recibir una variable como la planteas?

Comment: Estoy 100% seguro que no has estudiado nada de css ni de html ni de javascript antes de venir a pregunta ... y eso es malo, malo, malo...

Comment: de paso te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: toy eprendiendo :v voy poco a poco. grax por la info @FranciscoNuñezIALover

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar una [@property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property), que pertenecen a un set de mejoras a css llamadas [CSS Houdini](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Houdini_APIs)

Basicamente creas una nueva propiedad CSS, muy parecido a lo que son las variables css (`var(--mivar)`) y luego puedes cambiar dicha propiedad con javascript como si fuera cualquier propiedad.

Ejemplo:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const angulo = UnCuadro.computedStyleMap().get('--angulo');
  
  UnCuadro.style.setProperty('--angulo', CSS.deg(angulo.value+10));
},200);
```

```css
@property --angulo{
  syntax: "<angle>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0deg;
}

#UnCuadro{
  background-color: hsl(var(--angulo) 75% 25%);
  
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s
}
```

```html
<div id="UnCuadro"></div>
```